# how to update android studio with jar file

Tags: updates, android-studio

My current installed *AndroidStudio* version on Ubuntu is *3.0.1*.
I downloaded a `.jar` update patch file from [Google](https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-171.4443003-173.4670197-patch-unix.jar)

How can I use this patch file to update my IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Move the .jar file to android studio then run below on terminal with your own path to patch

```
java -classpath /path/to/AI-patch-unix.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install $PWD
```

move your sdk folder first to some other place if it locates inside android studio folder